# coupling method for first hitting times

Tags: reference-request, pr.probability

Consider a Markov process $(X_t: S \to S)_{t \ge 0}$ that begins with two initial probabilities $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ defined on the state space $S$. Let's define the first hitting time $\tau$ as $\tau:= \inf (t \ge 0, X_t \in A)$, where $A$ is a proper subset of $S$.

The question at hand is whether we can obtain a good estimate of the quantity
$|\mu_1(\tau > t) - \mu_2(\tau > t)|$ in terms of $A$ in the state space $S$ and the time parameter $t$. It would be interesting to have references or sources that can provide insights. Any recommendations would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Is the elementary bound by the TV distance between $\mu_1$ and $\mu_2$ insufficient ?

Comment: TV norm is $\sup_t$, but i also want to know how the decay depends on $t$

Comment: The idea behind my comment is: if there is sufficient overlap between the initial distributions, then the quantity of interest admits a uniform-in-$t$ bound.

Comment: is there a general theory to study the asymptotic of t? $\mu_1, \mu_2$ are general